# List of topologies on 5 element set

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Does anyone know of a list of the 139 inequivalent (i.e. non-homeomorphic) topologies on a space with 5 points? [Wikipedia does a list of inequivalent topologies on spaces with 4 points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#4_points), but I can't find one for 5. Of course, given the number, it might be understandable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See mathematrucker's answer to the math overflow question [Is there a list of all connected T_0-spaces with 5 points?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43069/is-there-a-list-of-all-connected-t-0-spaces-with-5-points) Near the beginning of his answer he writes the following:

> Since the number (139) of distinct 5-element topological spaces (up to homeomorphism) is manageably small and there don't seem to be any lists posted anywhere, I am posting one here.